# Prevent record from being edited after a certain condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app where I have a record called Listing that is in a `has_many` relation with Offer. Now a Listing can have many Offers, but when the Listing has an Offer whose :status is accepted, then I would like that that Listing can no longer be edited.

How should I go about this? I'm thinking about having a callback method like check_offer_status and then just use  a before_action on the Listings edit action? Is this a way to go or should I consider something else?

Comment: For the most basic implementation: **with an `if` statement**

Comment: There are all sorts of ways it *could* be implemented - like a `before_action`, or a conditional inside the main controller action, or encapsulated in a service object, or perhaps even part of an authorization `Policy` class. But at the end of the day, one way or another, it sounds like a relatively straightforward `if` statement would suffice.

Comment: @Daniel there is no single proper answer for this question - it strongly depends on the use cases and data access scenarios. For example, can Offer change its state from accepted back to something else? If so, should Listing become unblocked or not? If it must stay locked you might need a separate field for the Listing (say, `locked boolean`), but If it must become unblocked your approach might work too... Or it might not - it it possible to bypass AR callbacks/validations so if you need stronger guarantees you might need stronger db-level kung-fu (like triggers). Etc etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails way would be to implement the [`readonly?` method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-readonly-3F):

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :offers
  def readonly?
    offers.where(accepted: true).exists?
  end
end
```

This method is called whenever you save a record and will cause a `ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord` error to be raised. If you want to prevent the error and provide better user feedback you can add a validation:

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :offers
  validates :is_editable, on: :update

  def readonly?
    offers.where(accepted: true).exists?
  end
  
  def is_editable
    errors.add(:base, 'Listing cannot be edited') if readonly?
  end
end
```

This is however just a weak guarantee and is still prone to potential race conditions and anything that will bypass AR as described by Konstantin Strukov.